# How to detect change of PHP file - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I am quite new to iphone development, and looking for a way to find out a way to detect a change on a PHP page in webview.

When the app load the php page, it looks in a database and echoes out a result.

So i would like to know how to detect the job was done first, before reading the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php is done when the page is done loading.

This means that you should read the data when the page is done loading.

Comment: THanks, I need something like "Onchange" or "Listener". The PHP file has an iFrame and reading a code from somewhere else, so there is no way to detect if the document has been changed.